# weird issue with hyphens in elasticsearch using snowball analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have this situation where we have a lot of documents that have titles like US-2343 or FX-4321 .... I'm using the snowball analyzer as the default analyzer for the index, however I have this weird problem.

Say I have the following docs US-4321, US-2343, US-2300 ... 
When I search for "us-2300" the one document shows up as expected (hyphens are escaped in the search) however when I do a search for "us-23*" ... nothing shows up, but if I do a search for "us 23*" (note the space) then us-2343 and us-2300 show up

I'm trying to understand why it works this way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check how your documents are indexed using [Analyze API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html). As you can see your documents are indexed as two tokens: `us` and `2343`.

```
$ curl "localhost:9200/your_index/_analyze?analyzer=snowball&pretty=true" -d "US-2343"   
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "us",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 2,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "2343",
    "start_offset" : 3,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "<NUM>",
    "position" : 2
  } ]
}
```

When you are searching for `us-23*`, elasticsearch is trying to find documents with tokens that start with `us-23`. It happens because wildcard expressions are not analyzed. As you can see, `snowball` parser doesn't generate such tokens, so no results are return. When you are searching for two tokens `us` and tokens with prefix `23`, you get results.

Take a look at [`text_phrase_prefix` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/text-query.html). It might be more suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Analyze API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html), you will find how your title is broken into terms.

I think that US-4321 is indexed as us and 4321. When you search for "us 4321" (with a QueryString or a MatchQuery), it will find all us terms and all 4321 terms.

To answer more, it could be nice to have more details on your query.

If your title contains a "-" and it's important in your use case, you should use another analyzer.
BTW, using wildcards is more expensive (from the performance POV) than using a ngram or edgengram analyzer.

HTH
David

Comment: Ooops ! Too late! Igor answered faster than me ;-)

Comment: I see the whitespace analyzer handles hyphens the way I'd like, is there a way to combine that with the snowball analyzer

Comment: Yes, snowball analyzer is defined as the chain of standard tokenizer, standard filter, lowercase filter, stop filter, and snowball filter. You can create your own analyzer that will simply replace standard tokenizer in this chain with whitespace tokenizer. Alternatively, you keep using standard tokenizer but add [Mapping Char Filter] (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/mapping-charfilter.html) that would replace `-` with `_`. The standard tokenizer doesn't split words on `_`.